# unable to attach java jdk with eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have installed java JDK 1.6.0_03 , then I downloaded adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 and extracted it but when I double click  eclipse.exe it gives me error that "No java virtual machine is found after searching the following location C:/users/CEC/Downloads/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702/eclipse/jre/bin/javaw.exe"
I want to know how to attach java with eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following line to your eclipse.ini

```
-vm <PATH_TO_JDK>\bin
```

Comment: @farhan Have you changed the path? Can you show the edited line?

Comment: -startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-vm <PATH>\bin
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

Comment: You should replace <PATH> with the path to your JDK. For example : "C:\Programm files\java\jdk_1.6.0_03" or what ever you installation path is.

Comment: Yes ellipse found the path, but still not opening... so many errors are there first one is "java was started but retruned exit code = 13"

Comment: @farhan Which eclipse Version do you use?